# Não consigo mudar o state de uma widget Entry() em Python e Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

No meu código, minha `Entry()` o `state` está originalmente como `DISABLED`. Para habilitar a entrada, o usuário precisaria marcar um dos `checkbuttons`. Bem, pelo menos essa é a ideia. O que acontece é que eu marco uma das caixas, mas a entrada não é liberada para que se possa digitar nela. Segue o trecho do código:

```
self.sum_l = Label(self.root, text = 'Soma', bg = 'Lightskyblue2')
self.sum_s = IntVar()
self.sum_c = Checkbutton(self.root, bg = 'Lightskyblue2', command = self.Sum, variable = self.sum_s)

self.sub_l = Label(self.root, text = 'Subtração', bg = 'Lightskyblue2')
self.sub_s = IntVar()
self.sub_c = Checkbutton(self.root, bg = 'Lightskyblue2', command = self.Sub, variable = self.sub_s)

self.mult_l = Label(self.root, text = 'Multiplicação', bg = 'Lightskyblue2')
self.mult_s = IntVar()
self.mult_c = Checkbutton(self.root, bg = 'Lightskyblue2', command = self.Mult, variable = self.mult_s)

self.div_l = Label(self.root, text = 'Divisão', bg = 'Lightskyblue2')
self.div_s = IntVar()
self.div_c = Checkbutton(self.root, bg = 'Lightskyblue2', command = self.Div, variable = self.div_s)

self.entry = Entry(self.root, bg = 'white')
if any([self.sum_s.get(), self.sub_s.get(), self.mult_s.get(), self.div_s.get()]):
    self.entry['state'] = NORMAL
else:
    self.entry['state'] = DISABLED
```

Provavelmente é alguma coisa óbvia que eu não observei. Alguém pode dizer o que é?

Comment: Evite colocar fragmentos descontextualizados de código - vale apena colocar a declaração de classe e de método na listagem, e, se preciso, pular linhas dentro do método - por exemplo, as linhas que são repetidas para os widgets de sub, mult e div, poderiam estar marcadas com um `...` . Mas a declaração do método e da classe tornam mais fácil visualizar o cotnexto para quem for ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim - 
o que acontece é que quando programamos para responder a aplicativos desktop (e aplicações web modernas, com requisições assincronas) - a coisa muda um pouco da programação para terminal.

Não tem mágica possível: se você escreve um trecho de código como o acima, ele é executado todo de uma vez. Ai o programa fica parado espernado a interação com o usuário. Quando o usuário interage, uma das funções de "callback"  é executada.

No seu casoo seu `if any([...` é executado uma vez assim que a janela é montada, mas nao fica nenhum código monitorando se houve alguma mudança nos widgets que você olha na lista. A checagem é feita uma vez só.

Então, você tem que conectar uma função para ser executada quando as suas variáveis forem alteradas - e não colocar o código junto com a criação das widgets.

ISso pode ser feito por exemplo, com o método "trace" das `IntVar` do Tkinter: você passa pra ela uma função ou método a ser chamada quando ela é alterada - você pode mudar o seu if para dentro de um  método - e colocar um callback para cada uma de suas variáveis. A forma de fazer isso  "por extenso" - isso é, sem usar um `for` para configurar vários componetes deuma vez é colocar depois de criar cada uma das suas `IntVar`uma  chamada do tipo:

```
self.mult_s.trace('w', self.changed)
```

(O 'w' indica que a função será chamada quando a variável
for alterada (escrita))

E então você cria o método `changed` onde você pode colocar exatamente o mesmo `if` que você colocou acima:

```
def changed(self, *args):
    if any([self.sum_s.get(), self.sub_s.get(), self.mult_s.get(), self.div_s.get()]):
        self.entry['state'] = NORMAL
    else:
        self.entry['state'] = DISABLED
```

Essas mudanças devem ser suficientes para o seu caso.

Comment: Deu o seguinte erro:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: Changed() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given`

Isso também gerou um outro erro(não coloco tudo aqui pra não exceder o espaço) mas resolvendo esse, o outro deve ser resolvido também.

Comment: desculpe - `trace` chama o callback com alguns parâmetros extras - editeia resposta para aceitar um número indefinido de argumentos posicionais agora.

Comment: Agora sim o código está funcionando perfeitamente. Muito obrigado.